# Finding min and max value in C (while loop)

Tags: c, while-loop

I am new at C. I am having problems with finding min and max value with while loop.
Can somebody tell me how can I find MIN value without initializing min value with random number..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define STOP 0
main()
{
int n, min, max;
printf("unesite niz cijelih brojeva [0 za kraj]: \n");

scanf("%d", &n);
max=0;
min=999999;
while(n!=STOP)
{
    if(n<min)
        min=n;
    if (n>max)
        max=n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
}
printf("max broj je: %d, a min broj je: %d.\n", max, min);
    system("pause");
```

}

Comment: Unconditionally assign min to the first value you read.

Comment: min = n; before while loop starts.

Comment: @user3329166 because, thats the only way that my program works...

Comment: `max=0;
min=999999;` --> `max=min=n;`

Answer (score 1):

Problem was at line where i was initializing min value. The right code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define STOP 0
main()
{
int n, min, max;
printf("unesite niz cijelih brojeva [0 za kraj]: \n");

scanf("%d", &n);
max=0;
min=n; //here was the problem
while(n!=STOP)
{
if(n<min)
    min=n;
if (n>max)
    max=n;
scanf("%d", &n);
}
printf("max broj je: %d, a min broj je: %d.\n", max, min);
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Марко Лучић says `min=n;`

Code can also `max=n;`

Suggested modifications:

1- Initialize `min, max`

```
#include <limits.h>
min = INT_MAX;
max = INT_MIN;
```

2- Test `scanf()` results.  Only 1 `scanf()` needed.

```
while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n != STOP) {
  if(n < min)
    min = n;
  if (n > max)
    max = n;
}
```